# Make first column sticky in Time Grid fullcalendar Vertical Resource View

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am using full calendar io plugin for my scheduling tool.

I have fixed the header but I can't make the first column as sticky as it has time and I need to make it stay fixed when I scroll towards right end (due to many Names).
[click here Normal picture without scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLmFP.png)

[click here second picture little scrolled to right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cc6Xp.png)

Comment: Consider adding screenshots, and code of what you tested.

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to achieve this via the API. How did you fix the header? Show the code for that. Perhaps something similar can be done with the left-side column. Or you could make a [feature request](https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features) to get this included in the fullCalendar product.

Comment: you solved it ? - @arun